# how to get these value using python

Tags: python

I have some html resource likes:

```
<tr>
    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td>9.09</td>
    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="dn">XXXX</td>
    <td>XXXX</td>
    <td>XXXX</td>
    <td>XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td class="dn">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td>XXXX</td>
    <td class="upl">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td>XXXX</td>
    <td>XXXX</td>
    <td>XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
    <td class="dn">XXXX</td>
    <td class="up">XXXX</td>
</tr>
```

How do I use BeautifulSoup 4 to get all XXXX values? My current code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("URL")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

nameList2 = bsObj.findAll("td")-->this only show all information

for name in nameList2:
    print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: What do you mean by *this only show all information* ?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I need get XXXX value of each line ,not first row value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## BeautifulSoup.contents

BeautifulSoup has an attribute contents *(note: no method)* could be used instant of get_text():

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("URL")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
nameList2 = bsObj.findAll("td")   #this only show all information
for name in nameList2:
    print(name.contents) #will be a list like [u:"XXXX"]
```

during my tests the length of the list is always 1, so you can use:

```
    print(name.contents[0]) #will be u:"XXXX"
```

to get rid of the u: call the `__str__` method of the u class:

```
    print(str(name.contents[0])) # --> "XXXX"
```

hopefully it was helpful, for whatever you are up to,
Good luck

Comment: it works,thanks!but how to get each (name.contents) value?

Comment: use it in a ' for' loop, and append the name.content to an array, `array = []`<br>
`for element in nameList2: array.append(str(element.contents[0]))`